# I'm having issues with getting started and programming in Julia. Where can I go for Julia Programming support?

Tags: julia

So if I am a newbie programmer in Julia and not sure how to really get started or keep getting stuck with language-specific things, what are my resources to help me answer my Julia related programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's so many! See the list below:

Julia docs: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/

Julia Slack: https://slackinvite.julialang.org

Julia Discourse: https://discourse.julialang.org

JuliaAcademy: https://juliaacademy.com

Posting question on StackOverflow with the `julia` tag.

In general, the community is here to help! Please feel free to use some or all of these resources.

Comment: that content is better preserved in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/julia/info) for now. If you want to make a canonical you need much more support from the Julia tag followers and that is better organized on Meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcanonical%5D+documentation+is%3Aq

Comment: Don't use github to ask for help! That is for development of the language. Your questions will be closed immediately. The best place for questions is probably discourse, but stack overflow is ok. Slack for conversations.

Comment: Okay, I removed that!